# Groovy in Ant build.xml (with Java classes)

Tags: java, ant, groovy

I have to include Groovy classes into existing Java apps, and include Groovy into Ant's `build.xml` file.

What is the best way to configure Ant's `build.xml` for it?

Update: Are there more specifics in combining Java and Groovy compilations? Sequence of tasks?

Answer (score 2):

@VonC is correct about including Groovy scripting in your Ant build.

To expand a bit:

To compile `.groovy` and `.java` sources *together* for use in the same application, use the [`<groovyc>`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovyc+Ant+Task) Ant task.

See [Ant Integration with Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Ant+Integration+with+Groovy) for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

To use Groovy in your ant script, you basically have to [declare the Groovy ant task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task):

```
<project name="groovy-build" default="listSourceFiles">

<taskdef name="groovy"
     classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
<groovy>
    ant.... // some ant groovy directives
</groovy>
</target>
</project>
```

However, you have to be careful, in your ant.xml, to refer to fileset within your [current target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225063).

Answer (score 0):

You should define javac inside groovyc, like this.

```
<groovyc srcdir="${testSourceDirectory}" destdir="${testClassesDirectory}">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement path="${mainClassesDirectory}"/>
    <pathelement path="${testClassesDirectory}"/>
    <path refid="testPath"/>
  </classpath>
  <javac source="1.4" target="1.4" debug="on" />
</groovyc>
```

For more info have a look here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovyc+Ant+Task at section Joint Compilation.